# Bootstrap in xpages André dojo tab container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, partial-page-refresh

I am developing an application on xpages using Bootstrap. The main xpages has one tab container. In an action that is inside a button contained in a dialog (from the extension library), inside one of the tabs, in your oncomplete event I give a partial refresh on several elements. All are updated except the current tab that is all blank. Does anyone know if there is any restriction on using Bootstrap that is already shipped in the domino itself with the dojo tab container?

Comment: I have seen a similar issue with refreshing a tab in a tab container - but it's not related to Bootstrap. As a workaround wrap your content in the tab in a div and then try refreshing that div instead of the tab.

Comment: I did this but it did not help. I think the problem is that I'm giving partial refresh in a panel that contains the dojo tab container, so that a tab that was hidden appears.